# How to send data to database using form tag?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can send data to database but using  tag. I want to use  tag so that the validation in my page will show like "please enter a valid email-address", "password do not match" and many more.

The problem is when I use  tag it shows no validation but the data send to db.
But if use  tag it shows the validation, but the data is not entering into db.

Here is the view code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">
    <?php echo form_open(base_url("index.php/main/editClass"));?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            Course Code-Section
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="ccs" type="text" value="<?php echo $Course_Code_Section;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            Course Description
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="des" type="text" value="<?php echo $Description;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            School Year-Semester
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="sys" type="text" value="<?php echo $School_Year_Semester;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            Room
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="rm" type="text" value="<?php echo $Room;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            Day-Time
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="dt" type="text" value="<?php echo $Day_Time;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><b>
            Student
            </b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="stu" type="text" value="<?php echo $Student;?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $CID;?>">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"></label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-grad btn-rect">Submit</button>
        <a href ="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/main/index"class="btn btn-default btn-grad btn-rect">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

Here is the code that I am changing:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">
```

And I changed it to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">
```

When I use the form tag, the url shows this:

```
http://localhost/ams/index.php/main/showEditClassView?ccs=CPE+506-CPE42FA1&des=Software+Engineering&sys=SY+2016-2017+2nd+Sem&rm=A-225&dt=Saturday-07%3A30+AM-12%3A30+PM&stu=Ronnel+Gonzales&id=1
```

Comment: You are opening TWO forms, one in your modified HTML, plus one being opened using Code Igniter PHP in the line immediately following.

Comment: What TWO form? I can't understand.

Comment: This line open a form: `<?php echo form_open(base_url("index.php/main/editClass"));?>` And your change (`<form class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">`)

Comment: So how can I fix it? If I change the <form class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate"> to <div class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">. The block validate will gone (will not function).

Comment: See answer below, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you modify:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate">
    <?php echo form_open(base_url("index.php/main/editClass"));?>
```

to:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <?php echo form_open(base_url("index.php/main/editClass"), 'id="block-validate"');?>
```

So that Codeigniter opens the form tag for you, but we use `id="block-validate"` so your validation can run?

Comment: Thanks for this it is working. But I already made it working.
Using this code:
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="block-validate" action='<?= base_url();?>index.php/account/editAccount' method="post">

Answer (score 0):

Use method="POST" if you do not want to appear the values in the url.Hope this will sort your problem.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="block-validate" method="POST">
```

Comment: I tried it. Yes! the values in the url do not appear but it does not send the data into the database. BTW thanks for the help.